# How to fix the text size in flutter ignoring system operative's font size?

Tags: flutter, text, font-size

I could not fix the text size of my Text ignoring system operative's font size.
I read in internet and I found the I have to avoid the use of mediaQuery such as:

final currentScaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;

The funny fact here is I've never used media query:

```
Text( "Random Text",
                  style: TextStyle(color: myColor, fontSize: widget.fontSize),
                )
```

For some reason in some context some components add the textScaleFactor to others. This is different to native android programming.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was find a good vales for textScaleFactor and fontSize and set them myself.

Text(
"Random Text",
textScaleFactor: 1.0,
style: TextStyle(color: myColor, fontSize: 14.0),
)

So that now they are fixed .